# Is there an analytic way to diagonalise this infinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to know where lies its spectrum so that I can still believe in quantum mechanics.
The matrix is like this:

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 &  1  & 0 & 0 &\ldots\\
1  &  0 & \sqrt{2}& 0 & \ldots\\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{3}&\ldots \\
0  &   0       &\sqrt{3} & 0 &\ldots\\
\vdots  &   \vdots & \vdots     &\vdots & \ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

Is there any way to analytically get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert Israel's comments are spot on. There are no eigenvalues; the spectrum is purely absolutely continuous and $\sigma =\mathbb R$. This is not extremely easy to show; see Theorem 1 [here.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904506001699) (In fact just showing that this matrix, defined on finitely supported sequences, say, is essentially self-adjoint is not completely trivial.)

What is rather routine to show is that $\sigma=\mathbb R$. Here's a sketch: $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ is slowly varying, that is, $a_n\simeq \sqrt{N}$ for $N\le n\le N+L$, and this will work for arbitrarily large $L$ (provided $N$ is large also).
Now the Jacobi matrix with constant $a_n=A$ has spectrum $[-2A,2A]$, and since we can get arbitrarily large $A$ here, the claim follows.

Comment: I understood! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Every self-adjoint operator has a diagonal form, but this is the position operator. It's diagonal representation is obtained by transforming from the discrete basis (oscillator states) to $L^2(R)$ where it is multiplication by $x$. The spectrum is the real line.

Comment: It is exactly the position operator, but how can the real line be the spectrum of a matrix? If we can order it as a vector, it must be enumerable. How can we go from a discrete basis to a continuum one?

Comment: The "matrix" is not really a matrix: it must be understood as representing a certain densely-defined unbounded operator on the Hilbert space $\ell^2$.  As such, it can have continuous spectrum.

Comment: Continuous spectrum does not have a "diagonalization" in the same sense as for matrices: there are no eigenvectors here.